# Alexa - Not recognizing Invocation Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am having trouble with the `alexa skill` the invocation name is not getting recognized in device, however in test simulator it works fine. I am clueless about this. I have made sure The skill language and device language are same. I have already read the naming convention and Invocation name best practices, so please don't post those links here.

Comment: And you are using the same account on the alexa device as your developer account?

Comment: No I am not using the same account in alexa device, its a beta tester account.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the language(English-In or English-US) in which your skill is created and the language in which the device is set up are the same. If they are different it wont work in the device.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your skill matches the locale of your device. In this case the skill 'test me' was in the US so the UK device was not recognising the invocation name.

[image]

If it doesn't match, go to language settings and add new language.

[image]